# Не могу установить data атрибут

Tags: jquery, select2

Есть `select`, который используется с плагином `select2`. И мне надо использовать свои атрибуты.

```
<select name="city" 
class="custom-select" required>
<option value="" data-main="1">1</option>
<option value="" data-main="2">2</option>
</select>
```

После инициализации моих дата атрибутов (`data-main`) нет. Как правильно сделать, чтобы после инициализации они были?

Инициализация:

```
$('.custom-select').select2({
    dropdownCssClass: 'select-city-dropdown'
});
```

Comment: а как вы инициализируете его?

Comment: сниппет то сделайте нормальный с демонстрацией проблемы

Comment: добавил пример инициализации

Comment: а где и как вы проверяете эти атрибуты? (надеюсь не просто в инспекторе кода смотрите)

Comment: Мне это и надо чтобы в инспекторе дата атрибуты уже были

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vj6uare9/2/)

"Достучаться" до дата атрибутов в вашем случае можно так:

```
$('select').on('change',function(e){
    let dataMain = $(this).select2('data')[0].element.dataset.main;
    console.log(dataMain);
});
```

з.ы. на jsfiddle выложил т.к. тут редактор почему-то не воспринимает файл select2.full.min.js

Comment: Мне надо чтобы после инициализации в списке уже были эти дата атрибуты. Сейчас в вашем примере можно наблюдать следующее в коде:

<li class="select2-results__option" role="treeitem" aria-selected="true">1</li>

Comment: То есть атрибута нет

Comment: сформируйте конкретно задачу - зачем вам это?

Comment: Я по этим атрибутам буду скрывать и показывать нужные мне пункты: например для России показывать элементы с атрибутом data-main="russia"...

Comment: Обновил пример.

Comment: не совсем то, мне надо чтобы атрибуты загружались в li -> http://prntscr.com/pmy4j9

Comment: омг... Зачем? Это динамически создаваемые эл-ты... Их не рекомендовано использовать, да и не нужно это

Comment: Как их динамически создавать, если они уже у меня все выведены одним списком. И единственный вариант сортировать их по data атрибуту, который принимает в себя значение с сервера.

Comment: Обновил ссылку - убрал всё лишнее... Вам не нужно с ними ничего делать, единственное что нужно - работать с изначальным select. Не нужно никуда ничего добавлять. Динамически создаваемые я имел ввиду что их рендерит сам плагин select2 и с ними нет необходимости работать. Я в примере вам показал пример как скрывать не нужные вам пункты, откуда какое значение "прилетает" - не важно. Если вы не можете интегрировать данное решение себе то есть несколько вар-тов: вы либо в деталях описываете что и как надо сделать и вам тут помогут (80% уже готово), либо ищите человека и платите за готовое решение.

Comment: Я в деталях описал.

Comment: Так я вам и ответил согласно ваших деталей. Но вы продолжаете Говорить что надо вам что-то куда-то добавить. Нет, не надо ничего никуда добавлять. В скрипте есть строчка `if (this.dataset.main == 'russia') {` которая и скрывает эл-ты с data-main russia. Вам надо сюда подставлять данные, которые приходят откуда-то и всё, не надо ничего никуда добавлять

Comment: Получилось частично. Но проблема в том, что не получается отменить disabled при следующем изменении.

Comment: `$(this).removeAttr('disabled');` вот это поставьте перед `if (this.dataset.main == 'russia') {`

Comment: Решено. Действительно работает!!!